# Chaning iPhone app colors without resubmitting to app store

Tags: ios, colors, themes

So this is a hypothetical question that I'm just trying to keep in the back of my mind as I go into learning to develop apps.

I haven't made an app yet but I've had a few ideas and features that I think would be cool in some of the apps I have ideas for.

That being said I'm wondering if there are any possible solutions to being able to change the overall style and theme, or just colors of an app that is already on the app store without updating assets and having to resubmit and thus update the app.

I've never gone through the process off submitting an app to apple or pushing changes so maybe I just don't know enough on how it works but I assume that if you make a change, be it minor or major bug fixing you have to resubmit to apple and once it's live all the devices that have the app installed will be prompted to update correct?

If that is the case is there an solution for doing the above without having to go through that submission process?

Let me give a quick example. Lets say I have an app that has a header with a background color an inside it there is a logo and maybe a menu icon, then there are headings and other formatted text throughout the app that all have a similar color to the header. Some time goes by and the World Cup has begun in brazil, the greens are really cool, and I think my users would have a little kick out of a temporary color scheme change to celebrate the games. I want to change the header color and link colors and maybe my logo color or even a new football themed logo all together without having to push my app to the store again.

I'd be curious to see if it can be done and how one might go about it.

Comment: Yes that can be done, you could read the data from some webservice and use the [UIAppearance proxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) to style some part of your app and/or read the settigns and setting the appropriate color, font, etc.. on the UI elements. But that a answer with example code will be too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is can be done. Using Web service to get the image, colour or even frame value.

Firstly, You need a default theme in your application for those who cannot download other theme. If there is something wrong or no internet, then you can use it.

Secondly, Just download theme from web service and store it. And then show your new theme.

Answer (score 0):

To piggy back on what brian said, try using Parse. You can upload all of your images and have it download from there. Parse makes it extremely easy to do something like that!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be to host the stylesheet for your App on a web server, rather than packaging / hard-coding it in XCode, then you could just edit the stylesheet on your server and all Apps referencing it would update as well.

You could do the same with images and such for your logo.

Word of caution, with larger images or many images your App's performance may suffer depending on the number of HTTP requests being sent, meaning if your App goes viral it will probably run slower than if the stylesheet / images were packaged in the App.

Comment: Is there an easy way to hide the loading of that image behind a loading cover of some sort. Again I haven't developed anything yet so I don't know how you would do that, in javascript I would wait until the window is done loading and then hide the page cover showing the image, then since that image is cached or saved to the local computer the next time it fires up it would be quicker. Is there something similar in iOS?

Comment: @Jordan, to be honest I am not much of an iPhone / iOS dev, I just knew this stuff would work from my experience in Web Development, I've dug around in XCode a few times but I'm not very familiar with the interface / what it can do, sorry.